# Replace Java Applet for another Technology

Tags: java, replace, applet, deprecated

I have read that Oracle and Browser's Developers (Mozilla, Google, Opera and Microsoft) are going to consider deprecated the Java Applets soon (and block it).

I know there is another questions similar in this web site, but We have an aditional issue. Our applets handle local (client's PC side) hardware, like (for example) a  Smartcard usb reader or in another case an Biometric Reader (fingerprint usb reader). HTML5 and PHP doesn't have code to handle client's side Hardware. our webserver is based on Linux, for this reason I think we can't use .Net.

Can you sugest us another development technology that permit us embeed in a website "something" like an applet that handle client's side hardware?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a tricky question. My company handles printing from a Java Applet today, and are currently writing an auto-updating installable client instead in JavaFX. Perhaps that could be some solution for your problem as well?

Comment: Another solution is to write a plugin for the browser. Chrome allows apps and extensions to communicate with for instance a connected USB device.

Comment: Thanks for your Answers! days later I found some info about the official replacement would be Java Web Start. But I searched about JavaFX and I going to evaluate it. Browser's plugins would be nice, but I would like to release a new multi-browser support app (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, MS Edge)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) is good answer for you. It

> allows users to start application software for the Java Platform
>   directly from the Internet using a web browser.

Comment: thanks a lot!. day later, I found a site with information about it, and it says this is the advice of  own Oracle personnel: migrate applets to Java Web start.

Comment: @DanielPerez have you read this: http://blog.openmicroscopy.org/tech-issues/future-plans/2015/09/23/java-web-start/ ? It says that web start is not an alternative too...